# C# IL - call constructor

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I'm studying C# IL simple example and can't understand something. I've got very simple program:

```
void Main()
{
   C c = new C(1);
}
class C
{
   public C(){}
   public C(int i){}
}
```

there is CIL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  newobj      UserQuery+C..ctor
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // c

C..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  nop         
IL_0009:  ret         

C..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  nop         
IL_0009:  ret
```

I don't understand, how virtual machine will distinguish which one constructor should be call. There is two same labels and the only difference seems to be in pushing argument in main. Is there something more deeper when calling constructor? Maybe compiler are providing some meta-data to distinguish which one should be called?

So let's assume this:

```
void Main()
{
  C c = new C(1);
}
class C
{
  public C(){}
  public C(int i){ i += 1;}
}

IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  newobj      UserQuery+C..ctor
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // c

C..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  nop         
IL_0009:  ret         

C..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ldarg.1     
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_000A:  add         
IL_000B:  starg.s     01 
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

Now, how to distinguish which one to call, at the label-level we cannot distinguish it.

Comment: Is this about the call to the constructor or the body of the constructor? - You show that both constructor bodies are equal, but you only show the call to one of the constructors.

Comment: @Theraot - I would like to know how VM will know which one of this subroutines call, especially there is nothing provided in code what let us distinguish that. Should it be first C..ctor or maybe second?

Comment: You need to use a better disassembler.  Ildasm.exe makes it quite clear which constructor is used.  Do keep in mind that the `ldarg.0` opcode is for the hidden *this* argument, not the constructor argument.

Comment: @furkle `ldc.i4`, immediately followed by `newobj instance void Test.C::.ctor()` can be part of valid IL of a method. You don't have to clear the stack before each call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to make the experiment...

I used the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CallConstructorA();
        CallConstructorB();
    }

    static void CallConstructorA()
    {
        GC.KeepAlive(new C());
    }

    static void CallConstructorB()
    {
        GC.KeepAlive(new C(1));
    }
}

class C
{
    public C() { }
    public C(int i)
    {
        GC.KeepAlive(i);
    }
}
```

The following is MSIL got with Telerik JustDecompile for the class Program:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Test.Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static void CallConstructorA () cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: newobj instance void Test.C::.ctor()
        IL_0006: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::KeepAlive(object)
        IL_000b: nop
        IL_000c: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static void CallConstructorB () cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0002: newobj instance void Test.C::.ctor(int32)
        IL_0007: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::KeepAlive(object)
        IL_000c: nop
        IL_000d: ret
    }

    .method private hidebysig static void Main () cil managed 
    {
        .entrypoint
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: call void Test.Program::CallConstructorA()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: call void Test.Program::CallConstructorB()
        IL_000c: nop
        IL_000d: ret
    }
}
```

So you can see that the calls are different...

The first one says:

```
        IL_0001: newobj instance void Test.C::.ctor()
```

The second says:

```
        IL_0002: newobj instance void Test.C::.ctor(int32)
```

---

So, I'm gessing it is your decompiler that is not showing all the details of the intermediate code. In fact I did try similar code to the one above in LINQPad and there both call looks alike.

---

For the detail of how the annotation is done in binary... honestly I don't know.

Comment: "For the detail of how the annotation is done in binary... honestly I don't know." You can always read [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), specifically §III.4.21 newobj, §II.22.25 MethodRef and §II.23.2
Blobs and signatures.

Answer (score 5):

The actual code identifies the constructor to be called by a [`MethodToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  These are unique for each overload.

Your disassembler has an inadequate token-to-string conversion which is giving you only the name, which isn't unique, and cannot be assembled.  In constrast, `ildasm` converts the token into a full signature which is able to roundtrip back to a working assembly (using `ilasm`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm far from an expert in IL

easiest way to find out how, compile your example without passing `1` to the constructor

this line will go away: `IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1` which mean, i think, it will not pass an argument to the constructor.

do it again by passing 9 instead of 1, this `IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1` will be replaced by `IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 9`

Answer (score 2):

Used the exact same code you provided.. I see following IL, which clearly indicates the overload of Constructor being called -

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class ConsoleTest.C c)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0002:  newobj     instance void ConsoleTest.C::.ctor(int32)
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Note the **`instance void ConsoleTest.C::.ctor(int32)`**

And about IL, when in doubt, one can and should always look at the documentation.
Since you can Emit IL at runtime, most of the cases, documentation for Emit API will give you sufficient information. For example, in case of [`NewObj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj(v=vs.110).aspx), it clear states that constructor `ConstructorInfo` is required for `NewObj` opcode

"Assembly Format `newobj ctor`"

"The following Emit method overload can use the newobj opcode: `ILGenerator.Emit(OpCode, ConstructorInfo)`"

Comment: While there are many tools out there.. I always use the tools which are shipped by Microsoft, unless they don't have a feature I really need. I used ILDasm from .Net SDK, and would use external, but reputed tools like .Net Reflector. I know LinqPad is also reputed, but it's primary purpose is not dis-assembly, and hence will not be surprised if it doesn't give good results.. IMHO, these reputed tool authors should know better than shipping half baked features.. Which can confuse their users, rather than help.

Comment: @VikasGupta I'm pretty sure LINQPad shows a simplified view of the IL on purpose.

Comment: @svick Agreed.. but why? If someone is curious enough to look at `IL`, might as well show them complete and accurate picture.. I'd still call this half baked. They probably didn't have time to make it any better.. rather than "trying to keep it simple".